# How to execute the script through cmd or powershell generated by EF Migrations

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Earlier, i was using EF AutomaticMigrations in my project. It was still in Development Environment only. Now, we are going for the production environment and i want to use code-based migrations. I have generated an `InitialCreate.cs` migration file using `add-migration`
Then, i made some changes to my model and added a new migration file

```
add-migration AddNewPropertyToTable1
```

I created a script from the migration file using

```
update-database -script
```

and then saved it in a .sql file. I tried to execute this sql file through [msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files), but it gave me an error of:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.TableName" because it does not exist or
>   you do not have permission.

I am using CMD in Administrative mode and my Database Server is also configured with the user as Admin and have all the necessary permissions.
When i went through the script, there was nothing mentioned about the Database name. It was like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD [Property] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201708180946444_AddNewPropertyToTable1', N'SchoolLibrary.Migrations.Configuration',  0x1F8B08000A1E617494253858D7168E92C64B6216E22D756D519626AB025AFAD44BE16C298E4B212160C375706975E72F0 , N'6.1.3-40302')
```

Can you please tell me the following:
1. Am i following the correct steps ?
2. I think, we have to pass a connection string also to the .sql file. If, yes do i have to manually write it in somewhere or how to automatically include it using EF migrations?
3. Do i have to modify the .sql file like

```
Use DatabaseName;
Go
/////
```

4. What is the best way to run the script on client machine ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where are you running the ef generated script?